# Launching unity app from batch file

Tags: c#, bash, unity-game-engine

Im trying to use the integrated cluster rendering for unity. In order to do so I need to run my application from a batch file with certain command line options.

Here is he documentation
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ClusterRenderingDeployment.html

I tried to open the app in -batchmode using the command line however this wasn't what the documentation meant. So i'm struggling to understand how to do this.

The command i tried is `open ~/Desktop/PP/NewUnityProject/Buildtest.app -server 2 *:8888 *:* 10000`

I am using mac

Comment: Any signs of effort? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are the command lines you've used?

Comment: When you are using a mac, there is no need to include the batch-file tag :)